# React getting prop into child

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm having trouble getting a prop to a child component.
I'm calling the function like:

```
<ShowMedal debnr='55555' />
```

In the console I see the property is being passed.

Then in the ShowMedal component I want to pass the debnr to my API call, but it's not working.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const ShowMedal = () => {

    const [mpstotal, setMpsTotal] = useState([]);
    const [ordertotal, setOrderTotal] = useState([]);

    const getMpsTotal = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/mpstotal/${this.props.debnr}`);
            const jsonData = await response.json();

            setMpsTotal(jsonData);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
        }
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        getMpsTotal();
    }, []);
```

What am I doing wrong here? :)

Answer (score 1):

Inside arrow functions `this` keyword points to the *window* object, not the function body. Anyways, it's not a class, you can't access methods this way.
Just declare `props` argument and use it.

```
const ShowMedal = ({ debnr }) => { // props destructuring
```

and then

```
const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/mpstotal/${debnr}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrow functions do not have a `this` binding of their own and there for it cannot reference `props` from inside.

You can achieve the desired results in two ways:

1. Destructuring

```js
const showMedal = ({ debnr }) => { // console.log(debnr) = 55555 }
```

2. Passing `props` as an argument

```js
const showMedal = props => {
   //console.log(props.debnr) = 55555
}
```